# OpenCL 1.2: Passing struct with uninited pointer member to kernel

Tags: opencl

I'd like to do something similar:

```
typedef struct {
    __dontcare __constant Context * ctx;
    float memberA, memberB;
} MyStruct;

__kernel void doSomething(__constant Context * ctx, __global MyStruct * data) {
    data->ctx = ctx;
    ...
}
```

AFAIK in OpenCL 1.2 it is not possible to pass a struct for a kernel with a pointer member. But I'd love to pass a dummy, uninited pointer member and initialize it later from kernel code.

Is it possible somehow?

Edit:

If I do something like this (casting int to ptr and ptr to int):

```
typedef struct {
    int ctx;
    float memberA, memberB;
} MyStruct;

__kernel void doSomething(__constant Context * ctx, __global MyStruct * data) {
    // with using proper synchronisation and critical section protection:
    data->ctx = (int)ctx;
    ...
    float2 pos = ((__constant Context *)(data->ctx))->center;
    ...
}
```

Will it work? Is it safe to assume that the pointer size is 4 bytes on every GPUs?